# How to encode raw video frame with FFmpeg API

Tags: c, ffmpeg

I'm trying to encode a raw video frame 640*480 30 FPS in YUV420P format using FFmpeg API. This function encodes frames using the mpeg2video codec.
However, calling `avcodec_receive_packet()` returns code 1 (error).
What am I doing wrong? I want to get an encoded video buffer for further sending via TCP.
All error handling is omitted.

```
EncodeFrame(const uint8_t* rawBuffer, size_t size) {
    const AVCodec* codec = avcodec_find_encoder(AV_CODEC_ID_MPEG2VIDEO);
    AVCodecContext *codec_ctx = avcodec_alloc_context3(codec);

    codec_ctx->bit_rate = 200000;
    codec_ctx->width = 640;
    codec_ctx->height = 480;
    codec_ctx->time_base = (AVRational){1,30};
    codec_ctx->gop_size = 10;
    codec_ctx->max_b_frames = 1;
    codec_ctx->pix_fmt = AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P;
    codec_ctx->codec_type = AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO;

    avcodec_open2(codec_ctx, codec, nullptr);

    AVFrame* frame = av_frame_alloc();
    frame->format  = AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P;
    frame->width   = 640;
    frame->height  = 480;

    av_image_fill_arrays(frame->data, frame->linesize, rawBuffer, AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P, 640, 480, 1);

    avcodec_send_frame(codec_ctx, frame);

    AVPacket* pkt = av_packet_alloc();
    avcodec_receive_packet(codec_ctx, pkt)
    ...
}
```

Comment: What programming language is this, C or C++? Please do not use use the "c" tag for C++ and the "c++" tag for C unless you are actually asking about both.

Comment: My project is in C++, but this section is C code.